# References to for Quasigroup Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, quasigroups

Can anyone suggest some references (books or articles) to understand Quasigroup Theory. I need very easy to understand reference if there is one. Thank you very much.

Edit:
Note: I have checked wikipedia article before asking the question. Kindly do not recommend that. Thanks

Comment: I recommend the references from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup).

Comment: See Wikipedia article and the references there https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20especially%20in%20abstract,not%20have%20an%20identity%20element.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes personally. OP is asking for references, probably from people who have personal experience with the study of the theory.

Comment: Right @MarkoKarbevski, Thank you. Also, of course I have checked wikipedia article before asking the question. I need any other reference or standard book that someone has read or has any idea about. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you explain why the references from wikipedia are not useful to you? I am not convinced that you have studied them all already. You could add more context to your question. What are your prerequisites? How much group theory do you already know? What about universal algebra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wikipedia article on quasigroups, already mentioned in replies, has as complete a list of reference books as possible. If you specifically want to know the easiest book among those listed, it's the one by Hala Pflugfelder:

H.O. Pflugfelder (1990). *Quasigroups and Loops: Introduction*. Berlin: Heldermann.

It does not assume as much mathematical background as the others.

Regarding the rest of the references:

1. Bruck's book is still a standard reference, but is poorly organized and is not meant for beginners.
2. The books by Belousov have never been translated into English.
3. The Chein/Pflugfelder/Smith book is not a textbook but a collection of survey articles. It assumes some familiarity with quasigroup theory.
4. The book by Shcherbacov is not really a textbook but is useful as an all-in-one reference for work by Russian and Moldovan quasigroup theorists.
5. Although the introductory chapters of Smith's book on representation theory are self-contained, it is not an introduction to quasigroup theory. It is good for learning about Smith's work all in one place.